# How to rename a batch file

Tags: linux, filenames, rename

I want to rename a file from

```
Chat WhatsApp dengan A3 - 21.mp4
Mine.mp4
MoviMax_MV1_V016_2.106.001_20150227_2030_fbf.mp4
bedrock_server.mp4
```

to

```
test1.mp4
test2.mp4
test3.mp4
test4.mp4
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Are any of the existing files named as `test1.mp4`, `test2.mp4`, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
LC_COLLATE=C n=0 sh -c '
for i in ./*.mp4; do echo mv "$i" "test$((n+=1)).mp4"; done'
```

Remove echo if the printed actions are correct